# Do it() calls within a describe() execute synchronously?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, assert

it has been my understanding that execution of `it` calls in a test suite happen sequentially i.e. that one call won't execute until the previous has completed.  however, I'm seeing disagreeable behaviour where the callback for a second request is executing before the callback for a first request has completed

I don't know if my premise is wrong (as some on IRC have said, indicating that `it` calls are supposed to be independent of each other and can execute in parallel) or my implementation is somehow flawed

my question: if I wanted to test a conversation with a bot (where I need to await for a response from the server before issuing another request), could I do it as a series of `it` calls? sort of like:

```js
describe('conversation', () => {
   it('begins chat', () => {
      fetch(server + '?hello').then(res => {
         assert.equal(res, 'EHLO');
      })
   })
   it('login request', () => {
      fetch(server + '?login=xxx').then(res => {
         assert.equal(res, 'User logged in');
      })
   })
   it('get headers', () => {
      fetch(server + '?headers').then(res => {
         assert.equal(res, '0 xxx xxxx');
      })
   })
})
```

or do I need to do something like:

```js
it('conversation', async () => {
   var res = await fetch(server + '?hello')
   assert.equal(res, 'EHLO');
   res = await fetch(server + '?login=xxx')
   assert.equal(res, 'User logged in');
   res = await fetch(server + '?headers')
   assert.equal(res, '0 xxx xxxx');
})
```

in which case I need to substantially increase the timeout since the conversation may be long?

Comment: `it()` is synchonous, but `fetch()` is async.

Comment: So your second method is the correct way to do it.

Comment: `it()` can be given an async handler so it isn't necessarily synchronous.  what I'm wondering is whether the second `it()` can be made to wait for the first to complete

Answer (score 1):

`fetch()` is async. Your tests will *always* succeed as `it()` callback kicks off the `fetch()` operation and returns. At some later turn of the event loop, the `fetch()` operation's `.then()` callback is invoked and throws an exception (or not). That might or might not show up in the console long as an unhandled promise rejection.

You could use `chai-with-promises`. Or, even easier, use async/await:

```
describe('conversation', () => {

  it('begins chat', async () => {
    const res = await fetch(server + '?hello');
    assert.equal(res, 'EHLO');
  });

  it('login request', async () => {
    const res = await fetch(server + '?login=xxx')
    assert.equal(res, 'User logged in');
  })

  it('get headers', async () => {
    const await fetch(server + '?headers');
    assert.equal(res, '0 xxx xxxx');
  })

})
```

Do these tests have a dependency on each other? Test should be independent. If you're trying to test a protocol handshake, you might want to do something like this:

```
describe('conversation', () => {

  it('does the expected', async () => {
    let res;

    res = await fetch(server + '?hello')
    assert.equal(res, 'EHLO');

    res = await fetch(server + '?login=xxx') )
    assert.equal(res, 'User logged in');

    res = await fetch(server + '?headers') )
    assert.equal(res, '0 xxx xxxx');

  })

})
```

Comment: because it's a conversation, the issuance of a request must wait for a previous request to complete.  it sounds like `it()` calls are designed to be run in parallel and thus must be independent from each other.  but that begs the question as to why there are modules are there intended to parallelise them such as mocha-parallel

Comment: The individual tests (`it()` callbacks) run synchronously. However, `fetch()` itself is asynchronous; that is, it [synchronously] returns a promise. So each of your `it()` callbacks  invoke `fetch()`, ignore the returned promise and exit successfully, all in the same turn of the event loop. An individual promise returned by `fetch()` will _eventually_ resolve, but it doesn't matter: your test has already succeeded.

Comment: and by "succeeded" you mean that it terminated without issuing an exception? or returning a promise rejection?

Comment: Mocha test callbacks can be either synchronous (`it('sync', function() {...});`) or asynchronous (`it('async', async function() {...});`). In the synchronous case, the test succeeds when the test callback exits without throwing an exception. In the asynchronous case, the test [eventually] succeeds when the Promise returned by the async _resolves_ rather than _rejects_.